# How to avoid unintended touch-inputs in an android app?

Tags: android, touch

for research purposes I am developing a native Android app (with Java), which allows geriatric patients after an ambulatory rehab to record a nutrition diary.

Due to the high age of the target group it has to be taken into account that the users have a tremor in their hands.

My approach to avoid "unintended" inputs:
Is there some kind of global setting that defines a "minimum time" between two touch inputs? If this time is underrun, the app only executes the first input and ignores further inputs within this timeframe.

Of course I am open for other approaches and ideas. Maybe Android itself provides input assistance for people with tremor? So far I could not find anything that helps me with this topic.

To give you an idea of the situation:
The user clicks a button. This causes the UI to change and a new button to appear in the exact same place where the user clicked. This button should not be directly "clickable". But of course, buttons at other locations should not react directly either.

Comment: How you will get to specify that this is an unintended touch?

Comment: My point of view is you have two buttons, they are nearby to each other. If the user is trying to click the first button but clicked the second one. This scenario you want to handle?

Comment: When a button is clicked, remember the time when it was clicked (`System.currentTimeMillis()`), set a final "noClickWithinThisAmountOfMS" and perform a simple check against that in the buttons' onClickListeners: `if((newTime - oldTime) > noClickWithinThisAmountOfMS)`, then don't ignore the click.

Comment: @HappySingh you're right. I cannot be sure, that these inputs are unintended but this is my first approach.

The scenario is a bit different, than you described. The user clicks a button, the UI refreshes and on the exact same spot as the user clicked will be a new button, which shouldn't be pressed unintended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember when the last `Button` was clicked, then compare that time to the time the next `Button` was clicked:

```
final long noClickWithinThisAmountOfMS = 2000; //2000ms = 2 seconds
long oldTime = 0;
long newTime = 0;
Button buttonOne = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
Button buttonTwo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_two);

buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if((newTime - oldTime) > noClickWithinThisAmountOfMS) {
            //Don't ignore the click
            oldTime = newTime;

            //TODO: Add actual "onClick" code here

        } //else: Ignore the click
    }
});

buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if((newTime - oldTime) > noClickWithinThisAmountOfMS) {
            oldTime = newTime;
            //TODO: Add actual "onClick" code here
        }
    }
});
```

Do this for every `Button` that has to be affected.

You can even create "clusters" of buttons this way by using multiple `oldTime` and `newTime` if e.g. ButtonOne and ButtonTwo are next to each other but should act independently of ButtonThree and ButtonFour.

Comment: I will also suggest to change the state of the buttons (when the the user can/can't press)

Comment: How would you share the `oldTime` between different activities? Just normal with an intent?

Comment: @DemoDemo If you disable a button, it also won't be clickable anymore, which means that OP would have to have a thread running in the background that enables the buttons again after x seconds. Plus, I'm not sure if disabling a button also changes the way it looks because if it does, I wouldn't do it because it would confuse the users.

Comment: @danielk You can, yes. You can also store it as a static long in an extra class to access it from multiple activities/fragments. You wrote that you replace the button with a new one in the same spot. How long does this switch take appr.? If you set `noClickWithinThisAmountOfMS` to e.g. 2s and the switch takes 2s, then this obviously wouldn't be necessary. Maybe think about "prolonging" the switch a little bit, so it's not instant, which would also give older users time to move their finger and "adjust".

Comment: @Neph The UI refreshes immediately after the user pressed the button. So there is no noticeable "delay". I think I will prefer the method to ignore input for a period of time, otherwise the users may think, that the app have crashed if they clicked an the UI stays the same.

Comment: @danielk In that case I would reduce the time between clicks to something like a second - long enough to not click again but not too long to confuse an older user with not reacting to input.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put all the buttons in an array and give them all the same onClickListener interface
which when onClick a for loop iterates over this array and disable each else button something like this

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>;
buttons.add(button1);
buttons.add(button2);
buttons.add(button3);
for(Button button : buttons){

button.addOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
    for(Button button1 : buttons){
       button1.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: This disables every button if you click on a single one but how do you re-enable them again? Buttons don't react to an `onClickListener` event when they are disabled, so you'd need some type of timer to re-enable them again. I can imagine that changing the state of buttons like this is an "expensive" way of doing it.